# How would I get the mean for each category? (H), (L), (UM), (LM)

Tags: python, boxplot

I have already created this boxplot, But I can't figure out how to get the mean for each individual category for Income group (https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0f0y.png)

I have tried this code: `data['Income group'].mean()` but it gets the mean for all categories and averages it out

Comment: what are you using to create the boxplot? matplotlib, plotly, seaborn,....? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It would be interesting to have a small code exemple, at least know what you use to create the boxplot and also what is the type of the data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `groupby()` method. It should be `data.groupby('Income group')['Internet percentage'].mean()`